# Modify ZIndex of an Items in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, z-index, itemscontrol, rendertransform

Here is the code of my ItemsControl that zooms on items when the mouse goes over.
I don't manage to increase the ZIndex of the current zoomed item to put it over the others.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5"
                                                        ScaleY="1.5" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

I tried to change directly the ZIndex in the trigger, but it doesn't work.
It seems that I need to change the ZIndex in the ContentPresenter that is the Parent of the TextBlock in the VisualTree and not directly in the TextBlock.

```
<Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="99" />
```

So I tried to change the ZIndex in the ContentPresenter, but it still doesn't work

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="99" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Does anyone know how it works ?

Comment: Works fine for me, using a Canvas. So you propably have another problem. What kind of panel do you use?

Comment: I use a WrapPanel. Which solution works for you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just tried exactly what you suggested in WPF 4 and it worked fine.

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="SO9687674.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2.5"
                                                        ScaleY="2.5" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="99" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace SO9687674
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new List<string>
            {
                "One",
                "two",
                "three"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What makes you think it's not working? Have you used Snoop to verify?

Comment: I think it doesn't work because I see it doesn't :) I snoop it and the ZIndex doesn't change when my mouse goes on. I'll try your exemple in a fresh project.

Comment: @Nicolas: at risk of patronizing, you are snooping the *container*, not the `TextBlock` itself, right?

Comment: @Nicolas the only way that is might not work is if you have something else writing the Zindex property. Check the [value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing), if something with a higher precedence is writing the zindex, the trigger value is "ignored", not really ignored but not used as long as a higher precedence writes the value.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks for your exemple, I managed to make it works. You put me back on the right way. I looked for the problem and I found that I have a concatenation of ItemsControl and I put the ItemContainerStyle on a wrong one :( Thanks for your useful help.